# Debug fails for C program in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I am a beginner trying to write a C program in Visual Studio 2010. I have created a new project and have copied my code into the empty .cpp page that appeared. The build is unsuccessful and when I try to debug, I get the following error message:

> Unable to start program "c:\users---\visual studio 2010\Projects\Homework\Debug\Homework.exe. The system can not find the file specified.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Provide the build error messages.  You can't debug until you have a successful build.

Comment: from context this is some part of your homework, if so mark it as such.

Comment: Also realize that you are technically not programming in C; VS is using the C++ compiler.  First, rename your file with a .c extension and then right click the project -> properties -> C/C++ -> Advance -> Compile As -> C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The build must be successful in order to create the exe file so you can start your application and debug. Check for compile errors and solve them before building your project.